# How well does Sencha touch integrate on a page?

Tags: javascript, html, sencha-touch, extjs

Lets say I have a Page to be displayed for mobile browsers which has some normal HTML table elements, some normal floated divs, etc

Now I also wanted to show some carousel kind of effect on this same page for the iPad..this carousel should be positioned in between 2 html tables. For this carousel, I decide to use Sencha touch..Now my question is how well does Sencha touch provide in terms of layout control so that I can place the carousel wherever I like and with as much width or height as I need ?

Does Sencha touch use absolute positioning for layout purpose ?

Also from a JS perspective, how well would it integrate with normal JS code ?

I am asking this question as before deciding to go witg Sencha touch for my app, I do not want to get stuck at a later stage because of limited control over Sencha components..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Sencha Touch carousels inside a Table. It will work just as it works for a full fledged Sencha Touch app. But if you do not use the layouts defined by Sencha, then you yourself have to take care of layouts and all.

You can use any html data and css with Sencha Touch. It works perfectly with other JS files. Its upto you, how you use it.

Comment: Thx a lot for the answer...So if I use Sencha touch for the funationality only and not for layout (height/width), can I control the same using normal CSS attributes...It would be really great if you could provide an example of the same..

Comment: Yes, Sencha Touch provides the same HTML and CSS functionality as normal HTML and CSS do. Just it provides a set of functionality on those components. So, just try to create what you want and test. It will work.

Comment: Ok..do u have any example of sencha touch along in a Java/Jsp page?